# Unified response/error handling in swift

Tags: ios, swift, oop, enums, afnetworking

Im wondering how to tackle such a problem:

**I have an application that lets user Log in with username and password. Then the application sends the credentials to API server and in response gets the logged user data**

in my Model i defined a User class

```
class User {

var id: String
var firstName: String?
var lastName: String?
var email: String
var permissions: String?
var birthday: String?
var subscription: String?


init(id: String, firstName: String?, lastName: String?, email: String, permissions: String?, birthday: String?, subscription: String?) {
    self.id = id
    self.firstName = firstName
    self.lastName = lastName
    self.email = email
    self.permissions = permissions
    self.birthday = birthday
    self.subscription = subscription
}
```

Then in a class called ApiConnector, I have something like this (using AFNetworking):

```
func loginUser(mainAddress: String, additionalAddr: String, email: String, password: String, callback: (success: Bool, data: User) -> Void){

    let fullAddress = mainAddress + additionalAddr
    var parameters = ["email":email, "password":password]

    manager.POST( fullAddress,
        parameters: parameters,
        success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,responseObject: AnyObject!) in 
            let json = JSON(data: operation.responseData)

            //HERE I HAVE A JSON WITH USER DATA
            callback(success: true, data: ???)
        },
        failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,error: NSError!) in
            let json = JSON(data: operation.responseData)
               //HERE I HAVE A JSON WITH ERROR
            callback(success: false, data: ???)
    })
}
```

Right now as u can see i have a callback returning User in the data field. But there is a problem when an error occures and i should be returning some ErrorType, not a User.

I was thinking how to unify the response so that i create something like

```
enum Result<T, E> {
case Ok(T)
case Error(E)
}
```

and in a Ok case return my User object. In case of Error return my ErrorType object - but kinda I cannot get my head around it.

Could anyone explain me how to do a unified response type in my case ?

(I placed the question marks instead of a type in code, cause thats what the question is about and I have no solution ATM)

Comment: If you can afford waiting a few months before shipping your app to the App Store, I suggest that you have a look at Swift 2 (available in the XCode 7 beta) and to its error handling features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with Optional and exchange success with decorated NSError to get nice error messages. For example like this:

```
class User {}
class ServerResponseError {
    var error: NSError
    var message: String {
        get {
            switch(error.code) {
                case 500:
                    return "server error"
                default:
                    return "unknown error"
            }
        }
    }
    init(error: NSError) {
        self.error = error
    }
}

func loginUser(callback: (user: User?, error: ServerResponseError?) -> Void){
    // something went wrong on server
    var error: NSError = NSError(domain: "", code: 500, userInfo: nil)
    callback(user: nil, error: ServerResponseError(error:error))
}

loginUser { (user, error) -> Void in
    print(error.message)
}
```

You can also decorate error object that will be returned from server and pass it the same way (with user nil). But i think it's bad practice to return 200 and error object.

Answer (score 1):

there is different ways to do this. One of these is to use in your `Callback` an `NSObject` :

```
callback: (success: Bool, data: NSObject?)
```

then in your success closure try a cast:

```
if let user = data as? User{
// you have the user
}
```

if this check fails try to cast to error in the same way..